# Password cracking using a dictionary and hashing

Tags: java

I'm working on an assignment for school regarding security and how to crack passwords using a dictionary. We are provided six hashed passwords, a dictionary of words, and a salt hash value. Three of the passwords are not salted, I have already cracked those. I am having trouble finding the three salted passwords.

I have my code set up to iterate through the large dictionary and hash each word and then compare to the hashed passwords. I've tried to hash the salt value on to the front and/or back of each word that I am hashing for comparison, but I can't find any matches. We're using three different algorithms (MD-5, SHA-256, and SHA-1). My program checks the length of the password hash and routes it to which algorithm needs to be used for cracking.

Here's an example of what I have running for the salted MD-5 password:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
           md.update((word + salt).getBytes());
        byte[] bytes = md.digest();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) 
+ 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }       

        return sb.toString();
```

"word" is the password sent in to be checked, "salt" is the salt hex in a string. This returns the value after hashing to a for loop that is running through my dictionary looking for a match. I can't understand why it can find the three unsalted versions but appending the salt to the front (or back) wont work. Obviously I'm misunderstanding something here. Any clarity is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible your salt is supposed to be raw bytes that are just represented as a hex string?  Maybe try decoding the salt first.

Comment: have you tried concating strings in reversed order i. e. (salt + word)?

Comment: I have tried concatenating in reverse order as well as decoding the salt first. However, I'm going to try each one more time now just incase.

Comment: This might provide some clarity for a solution. This is the salt file: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e

This is one of the passwords:
00b961e20655b8cb16fb7aff3d3a28a3

I'm confused as to where the salt would even go since they're both the exact same length?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
Base64.Encoder base64 = Base64.getEncoder();

ShadowRecord r = new ShadoRecord("username", "usedSalt", "hashedPassword");
if (test(r, "secret")) {
    System.out.println("Password is 'secret'");
}

public class ShadowRecord {
    public final String username;
    public final String salt;
    public final String hash; // result of hash(password + salt)

    public ShadowRecord(String username, String salt, String hash) {
        this.username = username;
        this.salt = salt;
        this.hash = hash;
    }
}

public boolean test(ShadowRecord r, String pwd) {
    String input = pwd + r.salt;
    String result = hash(input);
    return result.equals(r.hash);
}

// input = pwd + salt
public String hash(String input) {
    byte[] result =  md5.digest(pwd.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    byte[] hash = base64.encode(result);
    return new String(hash, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - unfortunately it's still not working.